# My computer keeps logging out by itself (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, logoff

This started happening a few hours ago. I will be using my computer and it just automatically logs out. It seems to occur when there are memory intensive tasks occurring. It's getting really frustrating because as soon as I start doing something it logs out. Any solutions?

Comment: First, find out if that's really what it's doing - check the system and application logs to make sure it's _just_ logging out, vs. something else.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Hit Windows+r then type eventvwr.msc to launch the event log viewer. (There are other friendlier ways to do it but that's how I do it) and then expand the selections on the left. You want to expand "Windows Logs" then look in both "Application" and "System" - the list of events will be shown in the middle. Scroll around, look for red/yellow colored events, especially around the time of day this happened. Good luck!

Comment: @MarkAllen thanks man I did what you said and I found a program that was giving some form of error. I uninstalled it and works seamlessly now.

Comment: The problem is still there I thought it went away but it didnt here is another person experiencing the same thing. http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121203155740AAyXlsV

Comment: Check the event log again, look for something crashing. Maybe check for online virus scanners or something.

Comment: @JoelDean, did you ever solve this problem? I had the same issue after doing an upgrade for someone http://superuser.com/questions/516766/windows-8-keeps-signing-out. They did a "refresh" and that solved it, except that it wiped out all non-Metro software.

Comment: @billweaver I haven't solved it, the problem still arises from time to time> I cant do a "refresh" because I rely heavily on my non-Metro applications. I don't even use the Metro side of the operating system.

Comment: @JoelDean - Yeah, "refresh" (or the effect of "refresh") wasn't intended in our case either. ;) So i take it you haven't found any further clues in the event log?

Answer (score -2):

I finally got a fix for this problem: Go to Control Panel-Personalization
change screen saver=screen saver settings. Adjacent to Wait Box is a small box: on resume, display logon screen, click in the box to remove the check and you will not be returned to the Logon screen when you resume work. You will see your screen saver but hit enter or any key and it will take you back to where you were.

Comment: I think OP means they are actively working when the computer logs them out. A screensaver would not have been launched in this case.